# how do you make a string dictionary function in lua?

Tags: lua, levenshtein-distance, edit-distance, jaro-winkler

Is there a way if a string is close to a string in a table it will replace it with the one in the table?

Like a spellcheck function, that searches through a table and if the input is close to one in the table it will fix it , so the one in the table and the string is the same?

Comment: sorry i am a slow learner , about handling strings.

Comment: You should compare your string with all strings in dictionary using [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance)

Comment: In practice, [Jaro-Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance) usually gives more realistically-looking results.

Comment: how do you implement the jaro-winkler distance in to lua scripts

Comment: I've used J-W a lot in Oracle DB.  I don't have J-W implementation in Lua, but you can write your own, just code that simple algo from Wikipedia.

Comment: i can't make high nor hare of what i am supposed to do with his algorithm [see](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ba49d2ef630a599848c412d62e62647edbaeb306)

Comment: You can also have a look at `soundex` algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code :) Reference code is from here : https://github.com/badarsh2/Algorithm-Implementations/blob/master/Levenshtein_distance/Lua/Yonaba/levenshtein.lua

```
local function min(a, b, c)
    return math.min(math.min(a, b), c)
end

local function matrix(row,col)
  local m = {}
  for i = 1,row do m[i] = {}
    for j = 1,col do m[i][j] = 0 end
  end
  return m
end

local function lev(strA,strB)
  local M = matrix(#strA+1,#strB+1)
  local i, j, cost
  local row, col = #M, #M[1]
  for i = 1, row do M[i][1] = i - 1 end
  for j = 1, col do M[1][j] = j - 1 end
  for i = 2, row do
    for j = 2, col do
      if (strA:sub(i - 1, i - 1) == strB:sub(j - 1, j - 1)) then cost = 0
      else cost = 1
      end
    M[i][j] = min(M[i-1][j] + 1,M[i][j - 1] + 1,M[i - 1][j - 1] + cost)
    end
  end
  return M[row][col]
end

local refTable = {"hell", "screen"}

local function getClosestWord(pInput, pTable, threesold)
  cDist = -1
  cWord = ""
  for key, val in pairs(pTable) do
    local levRes = lev(pInput, val)
    if levRes < cDist or cDist == -1 then
      cDist = levRes
      cWord = val
    end
  end
  print(cDist)
  if cDist <= threesold then
    return cWord
  else
    return pInput
  end
end

a = getClosestWord("hello", refTable, 3)
b = getClosestWord("screw", refTable, 3)
print(a, b)
```

Third parameter is threesold, if min distance is higher than threesold, word is not replaced.

Comment: thanks this will help development of my luabot a lot!

Comment: Good luck for your bot :)