# Lua - Finding the best match for a string

Tags: string, lua, pattern-matching

I was curious if anyone had a good method of choosing the best matching case between strings. For example, say I have a table with keys “Hi there”, “Hello”, “Hiya”, “hi”, “Hi”, and “Hey there”. The I want to find the closest match for “Hi”. It would then match to the “Hi” first. If that wasn’t found, then the “hi” then “Hiya”, and so on. Prioritizing perfect matches, then lower/uppercase matches, then which ever had the least number of differences or length difference.

My current method seems unwieldy, first checking for a perfect match, then looping around with a string.match, saving any with the closest string.len.

Comment: I think, you'll need the Levenshtein distance for this. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681501/how-do-you-make-a-string-dictionary-function-in-lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not looking for a perfect match only, you need to use some metric as a measure of similarity and then look for the closest match.

As McBarby suggested in his comment you can use the Levenshtein distance which is the minimum number of single character edits necessary to get from string 1 to string 2. Just research which metrics are available and which one suits your needs best. Of course you can also define your own metric.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric lists a number of other string metrics:

> Sørensen–Dice coefficient
>
> Block distance or L1 distance or City block distance
>
> Jaro–Winkler distance
>
> Simple matching coefficient (SMC)
>
> Jaccard similarity or Jaccard coefficient or Tanimoto coefficient
>
> Tversky index
>
> Overlap coefficient
>
> Variational distance
>
> Hellinger distance or Bhattacharyya distance
>
> Information radius (Jensen–Shannon divergence)
>
> Skew divergence
>
> Confusion probability
>
> Tau metric, an approximation of the Kullback–Leibler divergence
>
> Fellegi and Sunters metric (SFS)
>
> Maximal matches
>
> Grammar-based distance
>
> TFIDF distance metric